# Should a question about Blogger DNS settings be posted on this site?

Tags: support, scope, private-beta

If I have a question about Blogger which has to do with DNS settings (CNAME, A record, etc.) should I post it on this WebApps site (since it has to do with Blogger, a web app) or should I wait until the WebMasters site reaches beta?

Answer (score 9):

I would say this is a question for Webmasters. Not a question for end-users of web applications.