# What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version

Tags: support, faq, scope

What kind of questions can I ask on this site?

Are there detailed examples of what's on-topic here?

Answer (score 6):

This post will be used to have a central repository of all content that is on-topic within this site. This is to be used as an extension of the general [FAQ: What questions can I ask here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

General questions can be added as comments to this question
or as a new [question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.

---

## Scope of questions

For the [main](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Web Applications site

### Ask

| Categories | Discussions |
| --- | --- |
| Shopping web applications | - [Should questions that ask about using “web shops” be allowed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/) [Are storefront sites like eBay, Apple App Store and Amazon considered to be "web applications"?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4578/) |
| Productivity | [Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4190/) |
| Business Process | [Are questions about corporate applications on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4346/) |
| Automation with Web IDE | [Should questions about Google Apps Scripts be allowed on WebApps?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/) |

### Clarification

| Categories | Discussions |
| --- | --- |
| WordPress, Google Sites | - [What should we do with WordPress questions and how tag them?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/) [What makes a Google Sites question off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4419/) |
| Using browsers for use with a web application | - [Are questions about browsers appropriate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/) [Are questions about browsers accepted as long as they are related to using a web application?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/) |
| Cross-platform apps | - [Are questions about Duolingo on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3746/) [Should general WhatsApp questions be allowed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4551/) |
| Busines Intelligence | [Do Power BI questions belong here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4155/) |
| Vendor Specific Mobile App Web Front End | [Should we allow questions about (Google) Recorder?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4975/) |
| Git Repositories | [Are questions regarding versioning software functionality on-topic here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4622/) |
| Troubleshooting | [Troubleshooting guidance](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/) (2015) [Troubleshooting questions are currently off-topic in this community; should we keep it that way?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4908/) (2023) |

### Don't Ask

| Categories | Discussions |
| --- | --- |
| Finding free assets | [Are questions about finding sites to get free <X> on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/) |
| Recommending free alternatives | [Should *free* alternatives be on-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/877/) |
| Identify this app | [Is this about identifing an interactive online IDE a question for Stack Overflow?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/510/) [Should <identify-this-app> style questions still remain on topic ?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/) |
| Etiquette or accepted practices in social media | [Should practices in social media be on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/940) [Are questions about etiquette on- or off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1160) |
| Creating websites | [Are questions about creating websites on- or off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38) [Are questions about self-installed web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/) (Updated March, 2016) |
| Domain name, DNS records | [Should a question about Blogger DNS settings be posted on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/104/) |
| Google Analytics | [Revisiting the decision on Google Analytics](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3713) (Update October, 2014) |
| Self installed web applications | [Are questions about self-installed web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/) |
| Wiki, Collaboration | [Can we ask any kind of wiki question here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/can-we-ask-any-kind-of-wiki-question-here) [Are questions about etiquette on- or off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1160/88163) |
| Gaming | [Are questions about Games on- or off- topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/) |
| Developing web applications | [If I'm working on a web app, do I ask here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/560) [Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685) |
| Using an API | [Are API questions on topic or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740) |
| Places to program online | [Is this about identifing an interactive online IDE a question for Stack Overflow?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/510) |
| Web services | [Is this site really the right place for Amazon Web Services?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4071/) |
| Adult web applications | [Questions about Adult apps that conform to Jeff's restrictions allowed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/) [Are questions about "adult" web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/) |
| Piracy | [Are questions about piracy off-topic here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463) |
| Requesting information for illicit or illegal use | [Should questions requesting information for illicit or illegal use be allowed?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684) |
| Mobile Apps | [Is my question aboug Google Launcher off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4599/) |
| Web browser features (i.e. bookmarks) | [Is Web Applications still the best stop for bookmarklets?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4580/) |

#### Use of Community Wiki

**Community Wiki** is special type of post were all users can contribute directly. Community Wiki were used, but should not be used anymore, for the following purposes (see custom close reasons section below ) :

| Categories | Discussions |
| --- | --- |
| Poll questions | [Are questions about which is the best/most popular <X> on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493) |
| Recommendation questions: Is there a web app | [Is asking "is there a webapp for x" on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/) |

## Related

### Custom Close Reasons

| Reason | Discussion | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| It is a question about creating/developing a web application. | [Re-phrase "web development" close reason](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/) | Questions about creating websites have been off-topic since the private beta. Ref. [Are questions about creating websites on- or off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/38/) |
| Questions asking for us to **recommend or find a Web Application** are off-topic and out of scope, as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. However, your question may be on topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you can rewrite it so that it meets their [quality guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) | [Please update the "recommendation" custom off-topic reason to include guidance to Software Recs](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3945/) | Recommendation became officially off-topic on 2014. This was discussed [Make all recommendation questions out of scope and off topic, regardless of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/), and revisited on a discussion derived from a new Area51 proposal. Ref. [Website recommendations](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3930/) |
| Questions that ask about the internal policies, technologies, and algorithms of web application companies are off-topic because only the company or its developers truly know the answer. Please see: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/). | [Do we need a close reason for questions asking about proprietary/non-public information or policies?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4614/) |  |

### Answering

| Categories | Discussions |
| --- | --- |
| Workarounds | [Answering with non web-based solutions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-it-accepted-to-answer-questions-with-non-web-based-solutions) [Are API answers to non-API questions appropriate here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2383/) [Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4059/) |

Comment: This is really confusing. I thought the "Scope" section was a list of things that were on topic, but surely you don't consider Piracy on topic. Are you saying that these links are where we can find whether one of those things listed in the scope are on topic or not?

Comment: @terdon I agree that this require more work. This FAQ was created during the [meta-tag:public-beta] that were a lot of questions about the site scope, naturally because one of the purposes of the public beta whas to clarify the site purpose and workings of the site at the time of validating that it deserves to "graduate". The links points to the discussions about each topic. The linked posts might need to be updated or clarified. It is also possible to replace the links by other posts.