# Are questions about etiquette on- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, etiquette

I have a question about the usage of a particular feature of a social network.

It is not a technical question, rather I wonder what is the socially acceptable way to do and what must be avoided when using this feature. (example for the "like" feature: using it on your own posts should be avoided).

Are such questions on- or off-topic on Web Applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these types of questions are off-topic.

Web Applications is about the *usage* of online apps. The actual etiquette is based on subjective social suggestions, something not suited for this site.

See: [Should social media be on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/940/should-social-media-be-on-topic)