# Re-phrase "web development" close reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

The current custom close reason for application development question reads:

> Questions about web application development are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

We're doing our compatriots at Stack Overflow a disservice. Most of these questions are crap.

I suggest rephrasing it:

> Questions about web application development are off-topic here; they *might* be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Perhaps a link to the Stack Overflow Help Center would be good, too.

---

Or, from Sathya's suggestion...

> It is a question about creating/developing a web application.

Comment: well over at [su] we got rid of the ["might be ontopic for x"](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6953/4377) completely - idea being, if it suits the destination site, it'll be *migrated*

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @Sathya you can set the change, sounds okay to me as well

Comment: @phwd added, you or Chris will need to approve it

Comment: @Sathya just approved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is now live:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts you're talking about recommendations. The question is above web dev and the position if off by one but the wording still remains the same.