# Should questions about Google Apps Scripts be allowed on WebApps?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should Google Apps Script question really be allowed on Web Apps? It may be a web application, but the questions relating to it usually always relate to a code question which does not seem suited for here. I know Stack OverFlow has a [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag and has people quite involved already in answering these questions over there.

Example of what I think should not be here:

[Is there a way to speed up the auto-increment routine in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46040/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-the-auto-increment-routine-in-google-spreadsheets)

I know in the past I have always asked my Google Script related issues on Stack OverFlow and never had any problems.

Answer (score 5):

*Should Google Apps Script questions really be allowed on Web Applications?* Answer: **YES**

GAS is an integral part of the web services Google provides. I strongly feel that anything in relation to the following services, is on-topic:

1. Google Spreadsheet
2. Google Sites
3. Google Presentation
4. Google Document

The only restriction is, is that it may not be full blown developments.

Do you realise how many questions about web applications (in particuar Google Spreadsheets, Google Documents) are being asked on Stack Overflow? We need to get those overhere. I'm glad that one of the experts on Stack Overflow found Web Applications: AdamL. He is a Top Contributor on the Google Product Forums for many years and recently gave some very good answers!!

Do realise that quite often, the answer contains a solution that involves GAS and not the question!!

Comment: The example question I gave, which you answered is purely a code answer. I thought that is not what web apps is suppose to be about.

Comment: @Fogest I see a lot of scripts/scripting as being part of web apps, though the line can certainly be blurry (e.g. oftentimes answers to questions involve using a webapp's API, which I definitely think is within the scope of this site)