# Are questions about Duolingo on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Doulingo.com](https://www.duolingo.com/) is a free language-learning app used by millions of people, but it has no tag here yet. So I wonder if questions about using Duolingo are OK here? Also, what would be the best place for them, according to the community here?

1. should they belong here?
2. should they asked on another SE site (which one)?
3. should a special site for Duolingo be produced through our Area51 (assuming it will get audience big enough - if advertised on Duolingo enough, this shouldn't be a problem)?
4. should they remain only on their forum and [wiki](http://duolingo.wikia.com/wiki/Duolingo_Wiki) and not to be discussed on SE?

Comment: If you're serious about trying to start a Stack Exchange site for Duolingo, please see [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AlE.: I know about Area51 - it's my highest-rep account. Now I'm just probing how much needed such a site (AskDuolingo) would be.

Comment: For what it's worth, there seem to be a number of questions on/about Duolingo on the various language usage sites: http://stackexchange.com/search?q=duolingo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Any question that has to do with using duolingo.com (Desktop not iOS/Android) is okay here.
2. See 1
3. no.
4. up to them

Comment: Not just _any_ question. Questions that are obviously support questions that only Duolingo can answer/act on are out of scope. Any questions that run afoul of our other rules (opinion-based, etc.) will also get closed.