# Is this site really the right place for Amazon Web Services?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have a number of questions tagged with [amazon-web-services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), [amazon-ec2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2), and/or [amazon-s3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3).

Is this really the best site for these questions? Okay, granted, AWS makes it really easy to spin up and provision servers using a web interface, but are they really web applications in the same way that Gmail, Twitter, etc. are?

I don't think so.

Compare to the same categories on Server Fault:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services
- https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2
- https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3

They have *thousands* of questions, a large portion of them with answers, compared to the only handful of questions here, most of which, if not closed, still aren't answered.

Even Webmasters seems like it'd be a better place:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3

There they've got dozens of questions, with a lot more votes and a lot more answers.

Look at some of the ones we have:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98891

  Asking about if its possible to host a Windows 32 application on AWS. Hosting isn't on-topic here; there's nothing special about AWS in that regard.
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98866

  Asking about setting up a CGI-BIN on a virtual private server. That's server configuration; just because you do it through a web application doesn't make it a question about a web app.
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95027

  Asking about configuration of email delivery rules. Again, not a question on how to use a web application.
- [Why can't I attach new AWS volume to existing AWS instance?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87739)

  Asking how to attach a volume to an instance. Again, I don't see how this is about using a web application; it's just that the tool happens to use a web interface.

---

Just because there's a web front-end doesn't make it on-topic for web applications. We don't accept questions about router configuration, and almost all of them use a web front-end. Except for maybe one or two exceptions, I don't think any of these questions belong here.

---

I'd also prefer not to turn off the spigot unless we have another place to send them. Can the Moderators here check in with the Moderators at Server Fault and/or Webmasters to see if they want AWS questions *carte blanche*?

Comment: We keep getting more of these, and they're more about server config than using an app. We really need to make this happen, but it'd be nice to get a bit more discussion here.

Comment: Just noticed that SuperUser are explicitly [directing AWS questions here](http://superuser.com/tags/amazon-web-services/info).

Comment: I have presented this to them https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11991/where-do-ec2-and-aws-questions-truly-belong @JohnC.

Answer (score 2):

Added the status of each of the questions mentioned in the question

> Look at some of the ones we have:
>
> - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98891 [DELETED]
>
>   Asking about if its possible to host a Windows 32 application on AWS.
>     Hosting isn't on-topic here; there's nothing special about AWS in that
>     regard.
> - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98866 [DELETED]
>
>   Asking about setting up a CGI-BIN on a virtual private server. That's
>     server configuration; just because you do it through a web application
>     doesn't make it a question about a web app.
> - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95027 [DELETED]
>
>   Asking about configuration of email delivery rules. Again, not a
>     question on how to use a web application.
> - [Why can't I attach new AWS volume to existing AWS instance?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87739)
>
>   Asking how to attach a volume to an instance. Again, I don't see how
>     this is about using a web application; it's just that the tool happens
>     to use a web interface.

Comment: "it's just that the tool happens to use a web interface." Isn't that true for a lot of things? Google calendar is a calender tool that happens to use a web interface. There are other interfaces, such as the android app. I think the last question *is* about using a web application.

Comment: The above comment is more appropriate for the question as it's the source of the criticized statement.