# What questions about the web user interface of a cloud computing service are off-topic and what questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I looked at questions about the web user interface of a cloud computing service  such as [amazon-web-services](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), [azure](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) and   [google-cloud-platform](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform), but I couldn't infer a consistent closing policy. What questions about the web user interface of a cloud computing service are off-topic?

---

My research:

[How do I increase my Virtual Server's clock speed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59750/how-do-i-increase-my-virtual-servers-clock-speed) mentions:

> Hosting is off-topic here. Asking about their web interface would be on-topic. –
> jonsca. Apr 22, 2014 at 5:54

[allquixotic](https://meta.superuser.com/users/144607/allquixotic) [mentionned](https://meta.superuser.com/a/11992/116475):

> Web Apps.SE: Really the only scenario where you might pose a topical question about AWS on Web Apps.SE would be if you have a question about using the (admittedly somewhat complicated) AWS Management Console. This is very much an "end-user" application, in that, the workflow involves putting in your login/password, then clicking through a bunch of links and buttons, entering data, etc. The format of these questions would be no different than a question about gmail's interface.

I see that 7 years ago, someone attempted to clarify the policy for AWS: [Is this site really the right place for Amazon Web Services?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4071/18147). But the closing policy wasn't clarified and AWS is just one of many cloud service providers.

---

Example of such questions about the web user interface of a cloud computing service:

1. [How can one obtain a AWS session token on the AWS website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120822/18147)
2. [Can I see how much AWS would otherwise be costing me if I weren't on free tier?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110659/18147)
3. [Azure DevOps Organization Setting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125576/18147)

Comment: Regarding referencing content, please follow the guidance from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/referencing:
`If you copy (or closely rephrase/reword) content that you did not create into something you post on Web Applications Stack Exchange (e.g., from another site or elsewhere on Web Applications Stack Exchange), make sure you do all of the following:

Provide a link to the original page or answer
Quote only the relevant portion
Provide the name of the original author
This ensures that the original creator gets credit for their work.` (the name of the original author is missing)

Comment: @Rubén ok, added.

Answer (score 2):

Most questions about AWS are off-topic at Web Applications Stack Exchange (webapps.se). Questions that might be on-topic are about using a web application as an [*end-user*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_(computing)) / [**power user**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_user).

A web application is a type of [application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software).

Most questions about AWS are about [system software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_software) / [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

Using a web interface to administer DNS host service usually will be off-topic at webapps.se because they are better served in other sites like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) (sf) and [Webmaters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (webmasters.se).

Using a web interface to administer an email service is usually off-topic at webapps.se for the same reason.

The same happens with questions about AWS.

Questions related to Azure depend on what is specifically asked. Azure is a brand that encompasses very diverse stuff.

Unfortunately, there isn't a rule of thumb about where the questions belong based on brands like Amazon, Microsoft, Google, etc. or even on the subsidiary / "child" brands like AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, etc.

P.S. Google Analytics is an edge case. It's a web application but is mainly used by **webmasters** in a professional setting. Google Analytics questions rarely get answers here as webmasters usually participate in *webmasters.se*.

---

##### Addendum

###### Part 1

I wonder if this image from [Cloud Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) might help clarify Web Applications SE's scope.

Cloud computing: Infrastructure, Platform, Application, Devices

[image: Cloud computing: Infrastructure, Platform, Application, Devices]

- Infraestructure: Off-topic.
- Platform: Off-topic.
- Application: Might be on-topic.

  - Web applications: might be on topic. Due to the broad scope of webapps.se, niche web applications, especially those pointed to professionals, rarely get answers here. We might think about finding ways to foster site-crossover collaboration, i.e., apps to handle personal finance might be attractive to members of [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com).
  - [Native applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_(computing)) (apps designed to run in specific operative systems): Off-topic.
- Devices: Off-topic.

###### Part 2

Site recommendation questions from Meta Stack Exchange (oldest questions first, might need to be updated)

###### Amazon Web Services (AWS)

- [Best Stack Exchange site for asking about Amazon AWS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141942/)
- [Where do we direct AWS configuration and management questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252122/)
- [Where can I ask general questions about how to use a service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335951/)
- [Where can I ask a question about Amazon AWS free tier?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366184/)

###### Azure

TBD

---

## Reference

- [Revisiting the decision on Google Analytics](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3713/88163)
- [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163)
- [Where can I ask a question about creating/developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)

Comment: Thanks. "Questions that might be on-topic are questions about using a web application as end-user." Do developers using AWS qualify as end-users of AWS?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Depends on what they are using at AWS and their role in using it. I.E., questions about [DevOps (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) are off-topic here; they might belong to [DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I see, so is [How can I affordably retrieve data from Amazon Glacier?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113175/how-can-i-affordably-retrieve-data-from-amazon-glacier) on-topic because the question isn't related to coding, [Cannot connect to the AWS web console from another computer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53566/cannot-connect-to-the-aws-web-console-from-another-computer) is on-topic because it's just about connecting to AWS but not about developer/webdev operations

Comment: and [Has Amazon Web Services‎ removing credit card option changed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/has-amazon-web-services-removing-credit-card-option-changed) is on-topic because it's just about payment/cost and not about developer operations?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't review each of them now.

Comment: No pb, I think I got it.