# Google Cloud will be Sponsoring Web Applications SE

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

### Update on March 21, 2024

This site sponsorship has been extended through June 30th.

---

### Update on January 24, 2024

This site sponsorship is now only visible to users in the US and Canada, due to the sponsor’s preference.

---

We're excited to announce that Google Cloud will be sponsoring Web Apps Stack Exchange beginning January 9th, going through March 31st. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: image of web apps SE home page with Google Cloud sponsorship logo in top right]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

It is important to note that Web Apps SE is not a Google Helpdesk, and should not be used that way. This sponsorship is an advertising agreement between SE and Google Cloud, it does not change the basic function of the site which is a community of users asking and answering one another's questions.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) "show questions tagged 'bug'") so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it! If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

And lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making this site successful.

Comment: Perhaps a similar announcement on several other sites is worth mentioning: [Google Cloud will be Sponsoring Cross Validated SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6624), [Google Cloud will be Sponsoring Server Fault SE](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9921), [Google Cloud will be Sponsoring Data Science SE](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2664) and [Google Cloud will be Sponsoring AI SE](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2942)

Comment: Is there a reason why they don't want users outside of the US to see this utterly irrelevant advertising?

Comment: @Valorum I can't to speak to the reasoning behind Google Cloud's wishes, sorry I don't have more info on it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the heads-up. I hope that Google knows that most questions about Google Cloud Platform (or other cloud compute providers) are [off-topic](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5028/18147) on WebApps SE and even questions that could be on-topic here tend to be migrated away
([example 1](https://serverfault.com/q/1144534/126950), [example 2](https://serverfault.com/q/1144890/126950), [example 3](https://serverfault.com/q/1144853/126950)). The sponsorship may therefore confuse users who aren't familiar with that policy.

Comment: It definitely seems like an odd match. I assume we'll be seeing Apple sponsoring *Android Enthusiasts:SE* next.

Comment: Google was made aware of the scope of the sites they are sponsoring, and the site sponsorship of course has no effect on what is considered on or off topic for a site. We do understand how the sponsorship could cause some confusion for users who may already be unclear on the scope of this site. You can feel free to link them to this post if that could help to clarify things for them.