# Do Power BI questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Microsoft Power BI has a web app, as well as a desktop application, that work together.

Would asking about the web app be appropriate, while the desktop would be inappropriate? Or neither? Or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that asking questions about the web interface would be okay, but asking about the desktop app would not.

We have similar situations with Dropbox (web interface, desktop sync tool, Android and iOS apps), Google Drive (same), as well as several more.

However, it also depends on the nature of those questions. I see an awful lot of [Power BI questions at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi).

See also:

- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerbi)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerbi)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerbi)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+bi) (no tag, but several questions come up on search.

I suggest Data Science would probably be better than here.

Comment: Data science sounds like a good fit. I didn't realize that existed.