# Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I frequently find myself in the unfortunate position of having to edit documents that are housed in Microsoft Word Online (formerly known as Word Web App). Often I find that Word Online doesn't behave the way I expect it to: either some functionality seems to be missing, or the interface is unintuitive.  Most of the time Googling my questions yields nothing, and the online documentation is likewise unhelpful.

Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here?  I don't really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online).

Not many questions, granted. I suspect some of them are incorrectly tagged with [microsoft-word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) which, as "installable software" is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sorry I missed that tag.

Comment: It may help to add a synonym for [microsoft-word-online]