# Can we standardize the Microsoft tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Last week there was [a Meta discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4190/60818) asking whether questions about Microsoft Word online were on-topic.

> Are questions about Microsoft Word Online on-topic here? I don't
>   really see any posted here, but perhaps I am not searching correctly.
>   <sub>-[mweiss](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4190/60818)</sub>

> Yes, they are. We even have a specific tag: [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online).
>
> Not many questions, granted. I suspect some of them are incorrectly
>   tagged with [microsoft-word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) which, as "installable software" is
>   off-topic here.
>   <sub>-[ale](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4191/60818)</sub>

When [a similar issue](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags) was discussed on Super User a few years back, they decided to prepend all microsoft product tags with `microsoft-`. I think this would be a good idea here as well.

- It makes the tag easier to find
- Makes finding microsoft-related questions easy by searching [microsoft*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft*)
- Consistent with Google's product tags ([google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive), [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), etc.)
- [Matches Microsoft's official naming scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLJHV.png)

**To prevent future confusion Microsoft's online Office apps should include the Microsoft name.**

Suggested retags:

- [office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-online) → [microsoft-office-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-online)
- [word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-online) → [microsoft-word-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-online)
- [excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel-online) → [microsoft-excel-online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-online)

**Edit**: **If the 25 character limit is a concern, an alternative would be to add the Microsoft tags as synonyms**

Comment: Do note that there is a 25-character limit for tags. Some product names may run afoul of that limit.

Comment: I don't see how this could help to prevent "future confusions". Could you describe the confusions that you are thinking on?

Comment: Searching [*-online] retrieves four tags, the three already mentioned and [tag:visual-studio-online]. `microsoft-visual-studio-online` exceeds the 25 chars limit, but this tag has only one question with no answers and no votes.

Comment: @Rubén The mentioned user couldn't find the tag for [office-online], presumably because they started typing [microsoft-office]. Though, I suppose a synonym would work equally well

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: IMHO the problem was the lack of questions not the tags. There are only six questions with [tag:word-online].

Comment: Related: [Clean up project: Office 365](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3952/88163)

Answer (score 1):

A terrible idea and synonyms would not work for this. The most I would contemplate is a solution that has been applied on Stack Overflow where I wanted to address a similar issue and [google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting) exceeded the character limit. So now [gs-conditional-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gs-conditional-formatting) is in use there, following the precedent set by [@Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) with [gs-vlookup](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gs-vlookup).

So possibly `m$-excel-online` but pointless given that Excel is a Microsoft Corporation [trade mark](https://www.cnet.com/uk/news/microsoft-registers-trademark-19-years-late/).