# Are questions about corporate applications on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Kronos Workforce Central](https://www.kronos.com/products/workforce-central-suite) is a cloud-based application for handling employee payroll, scheduling, and timekeeping. It is a commercial software suite licensed out to large corporate clients such as banks, hospitals, and manufacturers.

While Kronos WFC fits the definition of a Web App, I was unsure if questions about a commercial application like Kronos would be allowed.

Example questions:

- How do I delete a job from the Organizational Map Editor?
- How can I only display exact matches when searching employees?
- Can I navigate the timestamp editor with a keyboard?

**Are questions about corporate web applications on topic?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that they're on-topic, but it's unlikely you're going to get answers to your questions. Unlike, say, Gmail, the audience for such apps is much smaller and I wouldn't expect people who use most such applications to look for help on third-party sites.

We've had questions about similar apps, and they generally languish unanswered, and usually unvoted-upon.

But, who knows? Maybe your question will attract someone from the product's development/support team who can answer.