# What makes a Google Sites question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm trying to interpret why [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/110145/how-can-i-have-a-page-on-a-google-site-redirect-to-a-file-in-google-drive) was closed. My question involved my attempt to implement something on my Google Site. I was viewing the Google Sites system as a web application, and therefore my question was regarding how to implement something through that application. There is a tag on `google-sites`. So which questions on Google Sites are on-topic and which are off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

And deleted.

The close reason states:

> "It is a question about creating/developing a web application."

I suspect that the people who voted to close read the the question as less about using Google Sites and more about crafting the right HTML/CSS/JavaScript combo to do the redirect you're after. That would make it a Stack Overflow question rather than a Web Apps question. (For what it's worth, I don't think I agree with the closure.)

If you can edit your question to clarify how it's unique to Google Sites and not just a generic web development question, members of the community can review and, if they agree, re-open it.

Comment: OK. I see. So part of the issue is that the only viable solution to my problem might be off-topic, even if the question isn't, because the web application doesn't offer a way of doing this directly. If a few more vote to undelete, I'll edit the question to make it more clear that I'm only interested in implementing the functionality directly through the web app. If that can't be done, then the second-best solution is the closest I can get to this functionality within Google Sites/Drive. And a viable answer is that no such feature exists.

Comment: Undeleted and can certainly be reopened post edit.   It was deleted by the system as part of the normal "roomba" sweeps.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, since it's still closed and meets the criteria for auto deletion. We need to get it re-opened, too.

Comment: Undeleted, reopened.