# Should general WhatsApp questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes there are questions about WhatsApp, that are not actually related to the web application, like [`WhatsApp group with hidden numbers?`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78442/177684).

The thing is, that on WhatsApp, the app is exclusively dependent on the smartphone. So there's actually no existence to the web app without the phone (unlike other options like Telegram, Hangouts etc.).

So although it's true that WhatsApp has a web version, the question isn't related to the web application, rather to the platform / basic features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the feature available through the web version? If so, then it is acceptable here, otherwise it isn't.

For that particular example, I voted to close it, so my answer here shouldn't be surprising. Apparently not enough people agreed with me.

Comment: About the first part - of course. About the second - I'm with you on that question, I don't think it's related here. I hope someone could explain why it's related, because it's beyond my understanding