# Decision process regarding Greasemonkey scripts

Tags: discussion, scope

The page "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" mentions "Greasemonkey scripts".

**My question**: Is there some publicly available information about the **decision process** of mentioning "Greasemonkey scripts"?

**Why I ask**: I'd like to understand the decisions/discussions that went into defining the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3):

They are first mentioned here: [Are questions about browsers accepted as long as they are related to using a web application?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/136642). I wasn't there at the time, but it seems a logical extension from [bookmarklets](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/345/136642).

Of course, questions about *programming* a Greasemonkey script are a better fit for Stack Overflow, and if it's more of a generic JavaScript / HTML / CSS problem I'd definitely consider them off-topic. An exception might be made if the problem can be solved by 'intricate' knowledge of the web application being scripted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should learn what was the process followed to create Web Applications. This should take you to learn about https://area51.stackexchange.com/, then to https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=definition

---

Besides the link provided in [the other answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4745/88163), other links were "greasemonkey" is mentioned in the context of the site scope

- [Is Web Applications still the best stop for bookmarklets?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4580/88163)
- [The Tour appears to give contradictory advice about browser questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3816/88163)

The criteria that I apply is

- If the question is about a user-script that is centered on modify / interact with an specific web application the question might be on-topic
- If the question is exclusively about the web browser extension (i.e. how to install / uninstall it) the question is off-topic and might be migrated to Super User.
- If the question is about HTML/CSS/JavaScript and it's not centered on an specific web application it might be migrated to Stack Overflow

Comment: Both questions you linked to were asked **after** Greasemonkey scripts were mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, I ask what **has lead** to that mention, i.e. what happened **before**.

Comment: @root please edit your question to clarify that you are looking only the initial discussion(s).