# Is my question aboug Google Launcher off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

Is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122479/is-possible-to-reach-google-launcher-discover-news-or-saved-pages-on-pc, is it off topic? Let me ask a different question as an example:

**Question**: Can I use Instagram, the mobile app, from PC? Not run the app on PC, no no no, can you use Instagram from their website. If I want to run Google app on my PC, I'd [use this](https://www.bluestacks.com/), that's not what I want.

**Answer**: You can only browse photos from the website, it's very limited.

Is my Instagram question a valid question? Is my answer a valid answer? If there are valid, then my initial question is like that, if my initial question is not valid, then why not?

Another example:

**Question**: I cannot reset my Facebook password from Android, how to do it on PC?

1. We cannot answer questions related to mobile apps
2. You are asking to run Facebook APK on PC?
3. It's very easy to do just refer to [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=topq)

If your answer is number 3, then I believe my question belong to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the referred question is off-topic on this site.

While nowadays it's very common that popular "web applications" have a mobile app, this site's scope doesn't encompasses all the front-ends, it's only about using such web applications.

Even on applications like Instagram, WhatsApp and other software as services which their main functionality is available only on mobile apps, on this site only questions about their web front-end is on-topic on this site.

---

By the way, as it's usual on many application related questions, the answers are in the application help/documentation. Regarding the question discussed on this thread, from [Find your saved items][1]:

> Here’s how to find items you’ve saved from Google search results.
>
> 1. Go to [Google.com](https://www.google.com/).
> 2. If you haven’t already, sign in to your Google Account.
> 3. Do a search.
> 4. At the top, click Images.
> 5. At the top right, click View saved.

## Related

### Meta Stack Exchange

This question was discussed in Meta SE

- [Please don't allow a single mod the ability to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318826/289691)