# What kind of questions about Google Drive can I ask on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

It looks like I asked one question on 3rd January 2023, and the question. And then, I have tried editing my question and none of my edits worked. I feel that I have to ask some Web Apps question about Google Drive. [What kind of question do I ask?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.

> If your question generally covers …

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Take a look at [this meta question on another site](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8444/what-kind-of-questions-about-vacation-can-i-ask-on-stackexchange). There also, I am facing a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about **using** Google Drive web app (https://drive.google.com) are on-topic.

Questions about additional storage promotions, storage plans, customer service, support tickets, Google policies, technologies that make Google Drive web app work are off-topic.

Questions specifically about Google Drive mobile apps, installing or using Google Drive for Desktop, Google Drive API and other stuff that doesn't involve the use for Google Drive web app are off-topic.

When asking a question about **using** Google Drive web app please follow the guidelines provided on [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Please pay attention to the field labels and help and the panels shown to the right on each step.

---

Before posting a question, first try the Google Drive built-in help.
Open https://drive.google.com and click the help button ( it's circle having a question mark inside) located in the top of the screen, near  the right side.

Help button

[image: Help button]

Google Drive Top Panel

[image: Top Panel]

Note: The Google Drive Top Panel might be slightly different if depending on if the account have enable off-line file acces or not (only available in Chrome) and if using a Google Workspace Account.

The help menu options might vary from time to time, depending on the account type and the current circunstances like a recent change or an ongoing issue.

The basic features are the same across all the account types. Some features are available based on Google subscriptions i.e. Google One and Google Workspace Editions. Features exclusive for Workspace Editions might be administered by Workspace administrators.

Despite of the above the official help center is the same for all end-users, https://support.google.com/drive, but some content might vary depending on the account used to access, the location of the user, and the current end-user support programs and budget, i.e. contact support options.

**Tips for English as Second Language Speakers**

If English is your second language, please bear in mind that you will get more chances to find the help that you need if you use the terms used in user interface in English and /or the Google help resources originaly wrote in English than translating a term from another language to English, so it might be a good idea to temporally switch your Google account to use English or use a second account for your research efforts.

The same if you have are trying to get help about an error message. Try to reproduce the problem using an account using English so the error message will shown in English.

**Related**

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163)

---

As of January 6th 2023, we have 972 original questions answered.
Source [[google-drive] duplicate:0 isanswered:1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20duplicate%3A0%20isanswered%3A1)